# Reading chinese fonts to R through RODBC

Tags: sql, r, rstudio, rodbc, rstudio-server

I am reading data from sql table named auR from SGDB database

```
library(RODBC)
connection <- odbcConnect(dsn = "DB",DBMSencoding = "UTF-8")
pp <- sqlQuery(connection, "SELECT * FROM [SGDB].[dbo].[auR] (NOLOCK);")
```

auR table has a column which contains English as well as Chinese characters.
When I checked the pp dataframe, places where there were Chinese characters were replaced by question marks( ????? ).

I have to read the sql table through RODBC properly, so that the Chinese characters also come properly.

I was wondering how to fix the same.